# How to filter for max date based on ID? SQL Question

Tags: sql, select, amazon-athena, presto, trino

```
SELECT 
    Type,
    Sum(CASE WHEN Status IN ('Open', 'Pending') then 1 else 0 end
    ) as Unresolved
FROM ticket_table
group by Type
Order by type asc
```

There is a column called ticket_ID and last_updated_time in the same table. There are multiple rows with the same ticket_ID. I want to only aggregate/count ticket_ID where last_updated_time is MAX based off of ticket_ID.

I am trying to get ticket types and count how many are open/pending. I'm getting incorrect numbers--there are duplicate ticket_IDs. I want to only count the latest ticket ID.

I'd likely have to make a select statement in the 'from' clause to filter out all older records.

I tried this:

```
SELECT 
    Type,
    Sum(CASE WHEN Status IN ('Open', 'Pending') then 1 else 0 end
    ) as Unresolved -- WHERE MAX(last_updated_time)
FROM "dl_refined_wireless_freshdesk"."ticket"
group by Type
Order by type asc
```

But it didn't work because you cannot do WHERE MAX(last_updated_time).

Comment: `WHERE` is used for pre-aggregation filtering. For post-aggregation filtering use `HAVING`.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Clearly when pinned down this is likely a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: It is not helpful to give invalid code because it doesn't mean anything so it doesn't communicate to us what you wish or expected it would do. (And here it's not clear what bad code you mean.) Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. Please indent code reasonably. Good practice with multiple tables is to use a tiny mnemonic table alias with every table & column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [window function](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/) to get the result you want.

Step 1. Apply window function and get row_number() sorting by last_updated_time  per ticket_id,

Step 2. Apply row_num =1 filter and perform the rest of the logic in the provided query.

Here is the query:

```
WITH ticket_with_rank AS (
SELECT
    *,
    row_number() over(partition by ticket_ID order by last_updated_time desc) as row_num
FROM "dl_refined_wireless_freshdesk"."ticket"
)
SELECT 
    Type,
    Sum(CASE WHEN Status IN ('Open', 'Pending') then 1 else 0 end
    ) as Unresolved -- WHERE MAX(last_updated_time)
FROM ticket_with_rank 
where row_num = 1 
group by Type
Order by type asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Presto/Trino which Athena is based on provide `max_by` function which can be used in this case (also you can leverage `count_if` instead of `sum(...)`):

```sql
select Type,
    count_if(Status IN ('Open', 'Pending'))
from(
    select max_by(Type, last_updated_time) Type,
           max_by(Status, last_updated_time) Status
    from ticket_table
    group by ticket_table
    )
group by Type
```

Alternative syntax which potentially can work in Athena engine v3 uses some `row` magic:

```sql
select Type,
    count_if(Status IN ('Open', 'Pending'))
from(
    select max_by((Type, Status), last_updated_time).* as (Type, Status)
    from ticket_table
    group by ticket_table
    )
group by Type
```